# What is the scala way of extracting value from Option[String]?

Tags: scala

i am trying to extract aid and event_type from Option[String] what is the best scala way to extract those values and if not there get null as output.

```
val payload = Some({"event":"testApi",
    "data":[{"aid":"test","pr":"{\"id\":\"813da0e5-d9aa-4275-b9d4-5e84362b73bb\",\"event_type\":\"promo app loaded\",\"label\":\"beach apartheid\",\"total\":1,\"timestamp\":1617891494152}}]",
    "tv":"js-2.17.3"
    })
```

If I have this how to extract other then if else.

Comment: You can use `match` or `fold`, `getOrElse`, `orElse`, `filter` and other extractors, since `Option` is a monad, and then parse the stringify as `json` and then find the relevant value

Comment: If you want a literal JVM `null`, you can do `payload.orNull`. If you have some sane default, you can do `payload.getOrElse`. If you want to chain processing if value is present, use `map`/`flatMap`.

Comment: I really recommend to read this https://danielwestheide.com/blog/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type/ Simple and to the point, I'm sure it will answer all your questions

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what it is you are going to do with this payload afterwards. `Option` is a [monad](https://blog.redelastic.com/a-guide-to-scala-collections-exploring-monads-in-scala-collections-ef810ef3aec3), and all the standard operations like `.map`, `flatMap`, `.foreach`, `.filter`, `.collect` etc. apply to it. I really recommend that you read up on [scala monads](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/demystifying-the-monad-in-scala-cc716bb6f534) to get a good handle on it.

In a nutshell, you should structure your code so that you never need to do `option.get` to access the actual value, almost never do `option.isEmpty` (or `option.nonEmpty`, and very rarely if ever do `.getOrElse` (e.g. `val unwrappedJson = payload.getOrElse('{}')`).

I would also avoid pattern matching in most cases, despite what that book mentioned in the other answer suggests. It may be "most common", but is not "the best" in most cases (though, this is starting to get into the "personal taste" area, there is nothing technically wrong with pattern matching, except that it is not "monadic" and is therefore somewhat harder to read and parse visually).

Some examples of things you can do:

```
    def parsePayload(maybePayload: Option[String]): Option[Payload] = 
       maybePayload.map(json.readValue[Payload])
   
    ...
    
    def getLabels(maybePayload: Option[String]): Seq[String] = maybePayload
        .map(json.readValue[Payload])
        .toSeq
        .flatMap(_.data)
        .map(_.pr.label)


    ...

    def uniqueIds(maybePayload: Option[String]): Seq[String] = maybePayload
       .map(json.readValue[Payload])
       .toSeq
       .flatMap(_.data)
       .map(_.pr.id)
       .distinct

    ...


    def maybeData(maybePayload: Option[String]): Seq[Data] = 
       parsePayload(maybePayload)
         .fold(Seq.empty[Data])(_.data)

    ...


    def byId(maybePayload: Option[String]): Map[String, Seq[Data]] = maybePayload
       .map(json.readValue[Payload])
       .toSeq
       .flatMap(_.data)
       .groupBy(_.pr.id)
       .map { case(id, datas) => datas }
       
    def forId(maybePayload: Option[String], id: String): Seq[Data] = maybePayload
       .map(json.readValue[Payload])
       .toSeq
       .flatMap(_.data.filter(_.pr.id == id))
     ...

    def forId2(maybePayload: Option[String], id: String): Seq[Data] = 
       byId(maybePayload).getOrElse(id)

    ...

    def maxTotal(maybePayload: Option[String]): Option((String, Int)) = 
      parsePayload(maybePayload)
      .collect { case Payload(_, data, _) if data.nonEmpty => data.maxBy(_.pr.total) }
      .map { case data => data.pr.id -> data.pr.total }
         
    ...  

 
    def printPayload(maybePayload: Option[String]): Unit = 
       maybePayload.foreach(println)
```

Etc.

Comment: @ziggystar sometimes nothing, if you have a good default, but most of the time, it is just unnecessary and looses information (`Option.empty[Seq[Int]]` meaning is somewhat different from `Seq.empty[Int]` .. and in case, you could just do `option.toSeq.flatten` if you need to flatten it like this). And `Option.empty[String].getOrElse("")` is usually just kicking the can down the road, because you are going to do `if string.nonEmpty { ... }` somewhere anyway.

Comment: @Dima Thanks for the inputs really appreciated .One question as you suggested we have to do is to parse the payload a json to perform the match or filter the values out of it ?

Comment: @KumarPadhy Not sure what the question is. How to parse json? There's a ton of libraries that do that for you. My personal preference is [jackson](https://coderwall.com/p/o--apg/easy-json-un-marshalling-in-scala-with-jackson), but it is _really_ just a matter of taste and/or what you are most familiar with.

Comment: No I know how to parse I use json4s to parse.
My question was I have to parse to json always no other way correct and I have to keep 2 vals one parsed json string and other option[string]?

Comment: @KumarPadhy `maybePayload.map { p => parseJson(p) -> p }`

Comment: but as a side note, carrying original string over beyond parse seems a bit fishy :/ I would not do it.

Comment: @Dima I know this. The thing is, that `getOrElse` is *the* regular way to get out of an `Option` by providing a default in case of an absent value. This is totally fine and should not be considered wrong. Of course you can use it in bad way, like everything else. But it cannot be avoided in perfectly good code, because it sometimes is the correct thing to do (actually quite often).

Comment: @ziggystar if you really "know this", then you _know_ that "this is totally fine". :D It may well be "_the_ regular way to get out of an Option by providing a default", just like `.orNull` is "_the_ regular way" to get out of an Option by replacing the value with null ... But just because there is "_the_ regular way" to do something, it doesn't mean that doing it is a good idea. Yes, if you _want to_ "get out of an Option", this is the way. The point is that you should rarely if ever _really want_ that, because it is almost never the best thing to do. Especially, not in "perfectly good code".

Comment: @Dima It is possible to avoid `null` in Scala code, and it should be done if possible. Almost everyone will agree. But `Option[A] => A` is a totally different thing. Yes, replacing `None` by some special value (like `""` for `String`) instead of keeping the `None` is suspicious. But sometimes it is simply the 100% correct one and only solution: `def getPort: Int = (userProvidedPort: Option[Int]).getOrElse(8080)`. How would you avoid the `getOrElse` in this case? I hope you acknowledge that this is perfectly correct business logic, with a very clean implementation

Comment: @Dime Don't get me wrong. I like your answer. But I think it is problematic to tell newbies to avoid `.getOrElse`. There are often situations, where the correct thing is to get out of the `Option`, because it needs to be done. Then you will use `fold`, `getOrElse` or pattern matching. There is absolutely nothing wrong about this. But you say that this should (almost always) be avoided. This confuses people, because it cannot be (almost always) avoided. `get` and `isDefined` indeed should be avoided (as a rule of thumb). But even `getOrNull` can be useful when interfacing with libraries.

Comment: @ziggystar think the opposite: it is problematic to tell newbies to use the language wrong. There is nothing wrong with explaining and encouraging good practices. If you "get out of the `Option`", then you _can't_ `use fold, getOrElse or pattern matching`. And _yes_, there certainly _is_ stuff wrong with this. I explained it above t length. And you said, that you "know that" ... but then just keeps repeating "nothing wrong" :) Yes, `orNull` _can_ be useful in some cases, and so can `getOrElse`, or even just `get` ... just not to a newbie, and not as a rule.

Comment: @ziggystar why do you think `isDefined` should be avoided then? :) It's actually much less problematic than `getOrElse`. The only problem with it is that it is redundant, `.nonEmpty` is better and more standard. Other than that (and promoting bad coding practices, like `getOrElse), it's actually quite ok to use.

Comment: @Dima `getOrElse` is a total function that will never produce an error. `get` can produce an exception; that's bad. Also having `null`s around is bad, because later on you will  get an NPE in innocent looking code. `isDefined` itself is indeed not that bad; but it often goes together with `get`, so when you see it, you should be extra careful.

Comment: @ziggistar `if (p.isDefined) p.get else Nil` will never produce an error too. `p.getOrElse(Nil).head` will "produce an error in innocent looking code". That (whether something may produce an error) isn't a very good criteria to use ... I mean, it's good to think about it, just not in this context.  _Every time_ you think you need to "get out of `Option`", you have to "be extra careful", because (at least in well written code) there is _a reason_ for something to be an `Option`. And by "getting out of it" you are effectively dismissing that reason. Don't do it.

Comment: @ziggystar what's _even worse_ than producing an error (that is at least immediately noticeable) is having a working application, that simply does wrong things. For example: `def getPostion(stock: String): Option[Seq[Int]] = if (unwanted(stock)) None else positions.getOrElse(stock, Nil)`   ... `def getFoo()  = getPosition("FOO").getOrElse(Nil)` ... `if (getFoo().isEmpty) {  buyLotsOf("FOO") }`

Answer (score 1):

According to the book "Programming in Scala, 3rd Edition", published by artima it says:

> "The most common way to take optional values apart is through a pattern match."

Example:

```scala
def show(x: Option[String]): String = x match {
  case Some(s) => s
  case None => "?"
}
```

Comment: it's often largely a question of whether you _should_ take them apart - maybe you should continue going with `map`/`flatMap`instead.

Comment: Yeah currently i was following that and its hard to match if i have nested of patterns and difficult to read as well so I needed what is best scala way to extract over this .